# Laravel Nova: Storing the foreign key of the related file record (that contains the file path)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-nova, laravel-6

This question concerns Laravel Nova 2.5.

I have a User (Nova) resource class that contains a 'file' field. 
I don't want the file path to be stored in my users DB table, but in a general 'files' DB table.

I found this code snippet in the Laraval Nova documentation that explains how to store the file path in the related table. But I'm not sure how I can set the FK field (file_id) in my users table (As now this field remains NULL, when storing the user resource via Nova). The snippet I found comes from:

> https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/file-fields.html#customizing-file-storage

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

File::make('Attachment')
    ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
        return function () use ($resource, $request) {
            $media = $resource->media()->updateOrCreate([], [
                'path'=> $request->file('attachment')->store('/path', 'public')
        ]);
    };
});
```

My users table looks like this:

> - id (prim key)
> - file_id (unsigned int)
> - username (varchar: 255)
> - email (varchar: 255)
> - created_at (datetime)
> - updated_at (datetime)

My files table looks like this:

> - id (prim key)
> - original_name (varchar: 255)
> - generated_name (varchar: 255)
> - created_at (datetime)
> - updated_at (datetime)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming “files” table, I choose the name “items”, because the Nova resource of table will be same name with “use Laravel\Nova\Fields\File;”.

The basic solution for your problem:

```
// database\migrations\2019_11_01_103838_create_items_table.php
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('original_name',255);
            $table->string('generated_name',255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// database\migrations\2019_11_01_104145_add_column_item_id_to_users_table.php
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('item_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items');
        });

// app\Nova\User.php
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Gravatar::make(),

            Text::make('Name')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

            Text::make('Email')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'email', 'max:254')
                ->creationRules('unique:users,email')
                ->updateRules('unique:users,email,{{resourceId}}'),

            Password::make('Password')
                ->onlyOnForms()
                ->creationRules('required', 'string', 'min:8')
                ->updateRules('nullable', 'string', 'min:8'),

            File::make('Item file')
                ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
                    $oldName = $request->item_file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $newName = 'user_file_'.$oldName;
                    // Check file of user is exist or not
                    $user = \App\User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
                    if(!$user){
                        $item = new \App\Item;
                        $item->original_name = $oldName;
                        $item->generated_name = $newName;
                        $item->save();
                        $model['item_id'] = $item->id;
                    }else{
                        $item = \App\Item::find($user->item_id);
                        if(!$item){
                            $item = new \App\Item;
                            $item->original_name = $oldName;
                            $item->generated_name = $newName;
                            $item->save();
                            $model['item_id'] = $item->id;
                        }else{
                            $item->original_name = $oldName;
                            $item->generated_name = $newName;
                            $item->save();
                        }
                    }
                    // return $newName;
                    $request->item_file->storeAs('public',$newName);
                })
                ->onlyOnForms(),
            Text::make('Item File Id','item_id')->exceptOnForms()

        ];
    }

// app\Observers\UserObserver.php = To delete the variable $model['item_file'] generate by File::make('Item file') in field User Nova resources.
<?php
namespace App\Observers;
use App\User;
class UserObserver
{
    public function saving(User $user)
    {
        unset($user->item_file);
    }
}

// app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php = To register the UserObserver
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use App\User;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }
}
```